# How to use web3j in java to get the Ethereum new PAIRS event, and get the contract address of the new PAIRS

Tags: web3-java

How to use web3j in java to get the Ethereum new PAIRS event, and get the contract address of the new PAIRS。.

Here is part of my code, I don't know what to do

```
private static void listenForNewContracts(Web3j web3j) {
    try {
        web3j.transactionFlowable().subscribe(tx -> {
            Transaction transaction = web3j.ethGetTransactionByHash(tx.getHash()).send().getTransaction().get();
        }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```